# ScottPlot places unnecessary markers on (0,0) and (x,0) coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, graph, charts, scottplot

I have been trying to plot a simple line in ScottPlot, which starts at `(0,y1)` and ends at `(x,y2)` where both `y1,y2 != 0`. However, ScottPlot still places markers at the coordinates `(0,0)` and `(x,0)` .

How can I make the chart without these coordinates so that only the remaining points are graphed?

Example:

[image]

My Code:

```
WpfPlot plt = new();

double[] xs = xPoints.ToArray();
double[] ys = yPoints.ToArray();

double[] paddedXs = ScottPlot.Tools.Pad(xs, cloneEdges: true);

plt.Plot.AddScatter(paddedXs, ScottPlot.Tools.Pad(ys), lineWidth: 2, color: Color.Blue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was due to the padding. After I used regular non-padded x values, both `(0,0)` and `(x,0)` dissappeared.